# How do I change the background color of a cell in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame:

```
Server        Env.    Model   Percent_Utilized
server123     Prod     Cisco.       50
server567.    Prod     Cisco.       80
serverabc.    Prod     IBM.         100
serverdwc.    Prod     IBM.         45
servercc.     Prod      Hitachi.    25
Avg                                60

server123Uat  Uat     Cisco.       40
server567u    Uat     Cisco.       30
serverabcu    Uat     IBM.         80
serverdwcu    Uat     IBM.         45
serverccu     Uat     Hitachi      15
Avg                               42
```

I need to change the background color of Percent_Utilized column cell based on some condition. Tackground color needs to be red, yellow or green based on what is the number. I also need to highlight the whole Avg row based on the value of Avg under Percent_Utilized value.in yellow collo (red, yellow or green)

I tried this for changing the cell values under Percent_Utilized column:

```
def color(val):
   if val > 80:
     color = 'red'
   elif val > 50 & val < 80:
     color = 'yellow'
   elif val < 50:
     color = 'green'

   return 'background-color: %s' % color

df.style.applymap(color, subset=["Percent_Utilized"]
```

I get this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'color' referenced before assignment
```

I am not sure how to go about changing the color of whole row that start with "Avg". If the Avg value is greater than 80 then the whole line should be red, if it is between 50 and 80 itshould be yellow, and if under 50 then the whole line should be green.

I also need to write this to an excel file with the same color background.

Comment: The code you provided works fine after fixing the syntax error near else.

Comment: Please share exactly what code you are running to get the error. It seems like the "else" part of the code was not properly defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Lets work on your second demand: condition for two column: I randomly select this condition if the diff smaller than something it is one color otherwise another color:

```
def color(val):
    if val > 80:
        background_color = 'red'
    elif val > 50 and val <= 80:
        background_color = 'yellow'
    else:
        background_color = 'green'
    return 'background-color: %s' % background_color

def color_for_avg_row(row):
    styles = [''] * len(row)
    if row['Server'] == 'Avg':
        if row['Percent_Utilized'] > 80:
            color = 'background-color: red'
        elif row['Percent_Utilized'] > 50:
            color = 'background-color: yellow'
        else:
            color = 'background-color: green'
        styles = [color for _ in row.index]
    return pd.Series(styles, index=row.index)
df_new = (df.style
          .apply(color_for_avg_row, axis=1)
          .applymap(color, subset=["Percent_Utilized"]))
df_new
```

This is the output you may change the logic of your condition

[image]

I suggest you to take a look at [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) (Yes applymap can cause problem)

> Deprecated since version 2.1.0: DataFrame.applymap has been
> deprecated. Use DataFrame.map instead.

So just read the document and see what you can change here.

Save it with style using the following command

```
df_new.to_excel("dataframe.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: @w0w_python, Avg is a row value grouped by Env. I need to look at each row that has Avg and its value Percent_Utilized.

Comment: It will be benefit to share the data structure of your current data I am not 100% sure if I understand write or not .

Comment: @w0w_python it is in the original post data frame called df. Avg is the value of Server column. I am Averaging out the Percent_Utilized per Env.

Comment: I tried to run your code, I am getting 'Styler' object has no attirubute 'style' error

Comment: Can you provide the desired performance, you can draw it manually~

Comment: I apologize for bad understanding ......@user1471980

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255188/discussion-between-wow-python-and-user1471980).

Comment: @w0w_python, I know you answered this questions but I have a little issue remaining. I need to account for the empty row between avg and the next set up servers. Empty row need to be there

Answer (score 2):

your logic is not clear for example what if val =80,try to use elif instead

Here is an example:

```
def color(val):
    if val > 80:
        color = 'red'
    elif val > 50 and val <= 80:
        color = 'yellow'
    else:
        color = 'green'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

df_new = df.style.applymap(color, subset=["Percent_Utilized"])
df_new
```

[image]

Comment: @w0w_python, I am getting error: backgound-color = 'red', cannot assing to operator

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: python version 3.8.3, I am still getting that error: local variable 'color' referenced before assignment

Comment: Let me think.....emmm, the last thing I would try is to rename color to background_color.....But it is strange.... If still not work, please let me know.....

Comment: @w0w_python what about the row that starts with Avg, I need to change that whole row color based on the value on Avg, Percent_Utilized cell?

Comment: If this works, you can add condition (or def a new fucntion to map color) in your if elif and just like what you did on this case. And one thing pay atterntion is that your pervious version if .....if......if ....else it will only have two color becasue it is decided by the last if else statement.

Comment: @wOw_python's code should not generate the "color referenced before assignment" error because it uses an "else" to guarantee that color gets set to something.  In the original code with the `elif val < 50`, when `val` is exactly 50, then color doesn't get set to anything.

Comment: Uhh, makes sense, I didn't check this logic. Thanks a lot !!!!@Malcolm

Comment: Your logic is exactly right.  You also correctly handle `val == 80` with the `<=` which the original code missed.  Though, in general, it is probably better to not even worry with that check as if `val` is not `<= 80`, then it would already be handled in the initial `if` block.  Probably best would be `if val > 80: ... elif val > 50: ... else: ...`

Comment: @w0w_python, I am very new to python, would you be able to help out here with coloring the Avg row?

Comment: @user1471980 see another answer to check the detail. Hope this will help you. I appreciate your patience with this, just finished a meeting.

Comment: @wOw_python, In the original data frame there is a swace (empty row between each group), this code works for not having empty row. It does not when there is an empty row, how do you skip the empty row?

Comment: Try to add if empty then skip this logic in your code

Comment: @w0w_python, when I replace the empty rows with this line df.dropna() it works but I need the empty line. I get that boolean error.

Comment: I tried this if val= '': continue, I get TypeError: boolean value of NA is abiguous

Answer (score 0):

For dealing with the empty row you can

```
import pandas as pd

def color(val):
    if val == '':
        return ''  
    val = float(val)  
    if val > 80:
        background_color = 'red'
    elif val > 50 and val <= 80:
        background_color = 'yellow'
    else:
        background_color = 'green'
    return 'background-color: %s' % background_color

def color_for_avg_row(row):
    styles = [''] * len(row)
    if row['Server'] == 'Avg':
        if row['Percent_Utilized'] == '':
            color = ''  
        else:
            val = float(row['Percent_Utilized'])  
            if val > 80:
                color = 'background-color: red'
            elif val > 50:
                color = 'background-color: yellow'
            else:
                color = 'background-color: green'
        styles = [color for _ in row.index]
    return pd.Series(styles, index=row.index)

data = {
    'Server': ['server123', 'server567', 'serverabc', 'serverdwc', 'servercc', 'Avg', '',
               'server123Uat', 'server567u', 'serverabcu', 'serverdwcu', 'serverccu', 'Avg'],
    'Env.': ['Prod', 'Prod', 'Prod', 'Prod', 'Prod', '', '',
             'Uat', 'Uat', 'Uat', 'Uat', 'Uat', ''],
    'Model': ['Cisco', 'Cisco', 'IBM', 'IBM', 'Hitachi', '', '',
              'Cisco', 'Cisco', 'IBM', 'IBM', 'Hitachi', ''],
    'Percent_Utilized': [50, 80, 100, 45, 25, 60, '',
                         40, 30, 80, 45, 15, 42]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_new = (df.style
          .apply(color_for_avg_row, axis=1)
          .applymap(color, subset=["Percent_Utilized"]))
```

Result is:

[image]

Comment: Thlhis works but some how some of my cells have <NA> or nan values. Is there way to skip these lines?